# Datepicker jquery - How to skip next 5 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I create delivery order, when user select the date 
Don't show next 5 days & Weekends

Here is code for don't show Weekends, how to hide next 5 days?

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
   jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
   minDate: +1, 
   maxDate: '+2M',
   beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minDate: "+6D",` will hide the next 5 days from the current date. It does take into account weekends already being hidden though, I don't believe. If that is your desired outcome, this gets a whole lot deeper.

[Min/Max Date Docs](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)